# How to get the left coordinate of a span and add value to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/socc95bd/1/

JQuery:

```
var offsets = $('#ss').offset();
var left = offsets.left;
$("#hfYN").val(left);
alert(left);

$(".switch input").on("click", function () {
    var offsets = $('#ss').offset();
    var top = offsets.top;
    var left = offsets.left;
    alert("Clicked on inputs " + left);
    $("#hfYN").val(left);
    //find out whether or not YES/NO selected?
});
```

I need to know whether the "green selection" is on YES or NO. I tried adding the ASP HiddenField to store the value.

When the page first load, it alerts "243.#####" and the green selection is on the YES, When I click on NO, it alerts "243.#####" and then if I click on YES, it alerts "301.#####".

How can I modify so the number is the same when it first loads and then also when clicked.

Comment: you do realize that since your using asp.net hidden field , the target id would be '$("# " + <%=hfYN.ClientID%>) instead of $("#hfYN")

Comment: also, could you please tell what is your objective ?

Comment: I don't see this activity in FireFox: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rqhnja0v/ Also it would be easier to look for `.is(":checked")` I would think.

Comment: @DinoMyte... I have ClientIDMode enabled so that is not necessary.

Comment: The objective is to know whether the selection is a YES or NO and do some code execution from code behind.

Comment: Oops. Sorry missed that

Comment: @Twisty That didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Load the page and then click on "NO", the LEFT coordinate remains the same even though you clicked NO from a YES. :/

Comment: What I noticed when they page loads, that "Yes" input has `checked=""`. Yet "No" did not. When I look at the DOM for `$ss`, it's offsetLeft I think is first encountering a border line that is not there when it is moved to cover "no". Still digging.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you for the assistance. This is too much of a hassle and not worth the time (Not to say I don't appreciate your time). I will close this ticket as I found a different solution for toggle switch. Thanks again.

Comment: @SiKni8 Sad to hear that as I just posted an answer and someone might also be looking to find this same answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the value via `.is(":checked")` like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rqhnja0v/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var offsets = $('#ss').offset();
    var left = offsets.left;
    $("#hfYN").val(left);
    //alert(left);
    console.log("Init ss: " + left + ", input: " + $("#week").is(":checked") + ", " + $("#month").is(":checked"));
    $(".switch input").on("click", function () {
        var offsets = $('#ss').offset();
        var top = offsets.top;
        var left = offsets.left;
        //alert("Clicked on inputs " + left);
        console.log("Click ss: " + left + ", input: " + $("#week").is(":checked") + ", " + $("#month").is(":checked"));;
        $("#hfYN").val(left);
        //find out whether or not YES/NO selected?
    });
});
```

Results I got in console:

```
Init ss: 200.5, input: true, false
Click ss: 200.5, input: false, true
Click ss: 258.5, input: true, false
Click ss: 200.5, input: false, true
Click ss: 258.5, input: true, false
```

Comment: I won't delete the question because you posted an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: On page load, YES is selected and the console displays: `Init ss: 280.1166687011719, input: true, false`, When NO is clicked and selected, the console displays: `Click ss: 280.1166687011719, input: false, true`. As you can see the coordinate is still the same.

Comment: Which browser and version are you using. I am not getting the same results in FireFox 42